# Jquery $.get - separate elements

Tags: jquery

U use the following to load an xml file and it works.  However, if I have three elements of city as Atlanta, New York, and Las Vegas it displays them all in the firstrecord field.  I would like to only show the first found city on the field.  In a field called secondrecord I would like to show the second record found.  I have tried many ways without success.

```
$.get("test.xml", function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
var clientID = $(data).find("city").text();

var firstrecordval= document.getElementById('firstrecord');
firstrecordval.innerHTML = $.trim(clientID);

var secondrecordval= document.getElementById('secondtrecord');
secondrecordval.innerHTML = $.trim(clientID);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I would consider returning JSON if possible. It's much easier to consume in JavaScript.

Comment: I strongly second @TGH's recommendation. If you are generating this XML code on your server, generate JSON instead. It's just as easy to generate, and it turns into native JavaScript objects so you don't have to do any of this `.getElementById()` stuff. You can just access the data directly with normal JavaScript object and array manipulation. If you could give an example of your XML data, any of us could suggest an equivalent JSON format and simple code to access it.

Comment: The xml:   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tasks>
    <task>
        <city>Atlanta</city>
  <state>GA</state>
    </task>
    <task>
        <city>New York</city>
  <state>NY</state>
    </task>
    <task>
        <city>Las Vegas</city>
  <state>Nevada</state>
    </task>    
</tasks>

Comment: I am actually not pulling it from the server.  In this case, it is a file in the same location as the html.  I am open to a better method.  Anything that could help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you also share the html where the data has to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

If the Cities are separated by commas, then just split clientID with "," and do a null check and trim before displaying. Hope this helps.